# Mysql SELECT narrowing search

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

EDIT:That was fast. The reason why I have this is because the table is a pivot table between 2 tables one has "id" as primary key and the other "type" primary key

Hello.

I want the following:

Find only find "id" where "type" is 1 AND 2 AND 3

This is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `type` = 1 AND `type` = 2 AND `type` = 3;
```

The SELECT statment should only return one row (id = 1)

**Table**

```
id type
1  1
1  2
1  3

2  1
2  2

3  3
```

Comment: I think what Cudos wants is a query that will return an id that has rows for all 3 types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to know the Id then add the keyword Distinct and just select the id,
where there ***are*** records for the three different types ...

```
  Select Distinct id 
  FROM `table` t
  WHERE  Exists (Select * From Table Where id = t.id and Type = '1')
     And Exists (Select * From Table Where id = t.id and Type = '2')
     And Exists (Select * From Table Where id = t.id and Type = '3')
```

If you want to see the Id and the type then add the type to the select,

```
 Select Distinct id, Type 
  FROM `table` t
  WHERE  Exists (Select * From Table Where id = t.id and Type = '1')
     And Exists (Select * From Table Where id = t.id and Type = '2')
     And Exists (Select * From Table Where id = t.id and Type = '3')
```

if you want to see every row that has that id, then leave out the distinct

```
  Select id, Type 
  FROM `table` t
  WHERE  Exists (Select * From Table Where id = t.id and Type = '1')
     And Exists (Select * From Table Where id = t.id and Type = '2')
     And Exists (Select * From Table Where id = t.id and Type = '3')
```

Answer (score 2):

A row can't have a column with a value 1 AND 2 AND 3 at the same time. It's like asking you if you're "20 and 21 and 22 years old". You can only be one of them.

You'd want to do something akin to:

```
SELECT id WHERE type = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT id WHERE type = 2
INTERSECT
SELECT id WHERE type = 3
```

but MySQL doesn't support INTERSECT, so you have to do it by hand:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE
    id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE
             id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE type = 3)
             AND type = 2)
    AND type = 1
```

Comment: I won't deny that it's ugly-ish... but it's 3 queries where the top voted solution has O(n^2) queries (which could be optimized, but I wouldn't bet on it).

Answer (score 1):

Your search conditions are incompatible. Field 'type' can't be at the same time equal to 1, 2 and 3. Given the absence of INTERSECT in MySQL, you can join the same table two times:

```
SELECT id FROM 
  Table t1 JOIN Table t2 ON (t1.id=t2.id) JOIN Table t3 ON (t3.id=t2.id)
WHERE t1.type=1 AND t2.type=2 AND t3.type=3
```

This will build a cartesian product of rows with the same id and retain only those which have all three types you want.

Learning the basics of SQL can help you a lot. There is a lot of information around. (including MySQL docs)

Comment: Can you please point me to a table where this condition type=1 AND type=2 ANd type=3 can be true? Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand that select evaluates a predicate written in WHERE clause for a single row? It will always be false, unless something has recently changed in the relational model and first normal form.

Comment: fupsduck's answer says nothing about data. He pointed to a wrong query.

Comment: Kevin, there was no question at all. So everyone was free to guess what was the question -- "Why it doesn't work?" or "How can I get the result I want?"

Comment: No. It is a statement. I can interpret it as "why my code doesn't do it?"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using intersection of sets

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE type = 1
  INTERSECT
SELECT id FROM table WHERE type = 2
  INTERSECT
SELECT id FROM table WHERE type = 3
```

I am thinking if there is also simplier query but now I have no idea

Comment: MySQL doesn't have INTERSECT.

Comment: oops, my fault. I usually use Oracle and there is this implemented

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, couldn't you just add `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query?

Answer (score -1):

Your selecting for the impossible.  For each row, type can not be three things at once.

Comment: Kevin - please explain how for a given row in a database a field can simultaneously have three different values?

Comment: Kevin - I think you simply missed the point some of us were trying to make that the asker did not understand - that as initially stated his SELECT statement could never return a row.

Comment: He didn't ask anything. There is no "?" in his message even at the moment of writing this.

Comment: I was simply offering the asker some insight, which was not at all obvious to the asker, not a solution - this process is collaborative.

Comment: His insight was correct. Cudos' select had a predicate which was impossible, in the sense that it had no chances to become true.

Comment: I'm gonna go have a drink - you should to.

Answer (score -2):

You're doing something wrong.  You should not have multiple rows with the same id.  It destroys the point of having one.  Your id column should be a primary key that auto increments.

I think you should go back and reexamine your schema.  Or at least add more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: How can you make a comment about his schema without knowing the implementation?

Comment: Kevin, are you sure that you do understand what is written in the original question? No matter how does he produce this table, his select tries to evaluate predicate type=1 AND type=2 AND type=3 for a single row with a single value of type.

Comment: Kevin, I am commenting on his schema because he has an id column with repeating values.  That breaks the entire point of an id column.

Edit: And his edit clarifies what he's doing.  My post was made believing that id should be a primary key (which, frankly, it should be, and then he should have another column foo_id).

Comment: In the supplied data there is exactly one type value in every row. This predicate will be false for any row in his data. What he *wants* is a different question (yes, I understand now that he wants those ids which have all types in different rows), but he definitely is trying to do a *wrong* thing

Comment: We're trying to help him to understand his problem, right? He is doing a very wrong thing, so he definitely should know why it is wrong. You instead is focused on his problem -- that's ok, but why are you downvoting those who is explaining why his code doesn't work?